# NetworkStream.Read doesn't work the first time called

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ip

I have a simple tcp/ip chat program with a server and client. The first time I send a packet, it makes it to the client but during the NetworkStream.Read it stops execution and doesn't throw an exception. The next packet I send is read and processed perfectly. Another weird thing I noticed is that MyNetworkStream.DataAvailable is always false even if I get information from the server so I have to put a debug symbol and skip over it. I wish I could post all my code but it is long so I will post where I read and write to the network stream.

```
 public void Listen(int byteLength)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[byteLength];
            MySocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Read), buffer);
        }

        private  void Read(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            while (MySocket.Connected)
            {
            MyNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(MySocket);
            var buffer = new byte[((byte[])ar.AsyncState).Length];
            if (!MyNetworkStream.DataAvailable)
                throw new Exception("Data not available");
                MyNetworkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); <------Here it stops execution without throwing an exception
                string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                if(OnRead == null)
                    continue;
                var e = new CommandEventArgs( null, content);
                Control target = null;
                if (OnRead.Target is Control)
                    target = (Control)OnRead.Target;
                if (target != null && target.InvokeRequired)
                    target.Invoke(OnRead, this, e);
                else
                    OnRead(this,e);

            }
        }


        public void Write(string message)
        {
            try
            { 
                var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                MySocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, null);
                if (OnWrite != null)
                {
                    var target = (Control)OnWrite.Target;
                    if (target != null && target.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        target.Invoke(OnWrite, this, new EventArgs());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OnWrite(this, new EventArgs());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: One important thing about TCP is that it delivers the data as a stream, and not as packets. One Write call may arrive in pieces, and multiple write calls may arrive together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginReceive` asynchronously waits for a message and fills your buffer. You then start synchronously reading from the socket, overwriting the first message in the process.

You should call `EndReceive` which returns the number of bytes read, then process your buffer before trying to read more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's directly related to the problem, but you are using the `Read` method wrong. You are reading data into the buffer, but you are ignoring how much data was actually read assuming that the `Read` call always returns as much data as you request, so you are decoding the entire buffer eventhough it might not be completely filled.

Get the return value of the `Read` call so that you know how much of the buffer is actually filled with data:

```
int len = MyNetworkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement EndRecieve to get the complete data from the stream. Checkout the following example from MSDN :

```
public static void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar){
    StateObject so = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket s = so.workSocket;

int read = s.EndReceive(ar);

if (read > 0) {
        so.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, read));
        s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
                                 new AsyncCallback(Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback), so);
}
else{
     if (so.sb.Length > 1) {
          //All of the data has been read, so displays it to the console
          string strContent;
          strContent = so.sb.ToString();
          Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Read {0} byte from socket" + 
                           "data = {1} ", strContent.Length, strContent));
     }
     s.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: I can never get to the 'else'. When I get to s.BeginReceive, if all the data has already been processed it won't call Read_Callback until another message is sent. Is there a way to know how all of the data has been read for each packet sent?